# orientate a 3d plane from 3 given points

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Given 3 dynamic points, what is the best way to orientate a plane so that it intersects all 3 points?

[image]

I'm using Three.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the direction of the vector to orientate the plane, calculate the cross product of any of the 2 sides of the triangle

so, if your points are a, b, c

```
side1 = subVectors (a, b);
side2 = subVectors (a, c);
planeNormal = crossVectors (side1, side2);
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a geometry. Add a vertice for each point, and create a face. For instance:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(1,1,0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(1,-1,0));
geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ) );
geometry.dynamic = true;
var shapeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(shapeMesh);
```

Everytime you change the geometry, be sure to let three.js know:

```
geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;
```

Comment: is there a way to orientate an abject to this shape?

Comment: Your comment is rather vague. How exactly do you want to orient it? And this should probably be a separate SO question.

Comment: i found it hard to accurately describe my issue sorry: i need to rotate a car so that it has the same angle as the terrain

Comment: You should formulate it as a separate question. The response here seems to answer your original question, so pls accept it.

Comment: Okay im going to wait 12 hours. Them mark yours as the answer and re write a new question. Cheers

Comment: Also i if i could get the face angle of your geometry and then rotate my object to this that should work